# Transferring Large Folder from Phone to Windows PC

Tags: windows, android, storage, files-folders

My partner has about 50Gb of photos in a single folder on her Android phone and we need to clear some space. When connected to my Windows 10 machine, the folder takes about 10 mins to list. Then when I try and copy the folder or its contents onto my PC, I get an error message about something not found and the process aborts.

I've tried two different PCs, and I'm out of ideas now.

Any suggestions how to make this work please?

Comment: Try connecting the phone by USB so that the phone folder shows up in Windows File Explorer.  I have copied files but not 50 GB

Comment: "something not found" …Accurate reporting would help, rather than vague guesswork.

Comment: Try using a better quality cable, preferably a short data cable with a current form factor.

Comment: DO NOT USE MTP (MTP is an unreliable primitive protocol not designed to transfer large number of files). Enable Developer options and ADB on device, install adb on PC side and use a tool like [adb-sync](https://github.com/SelfAdjointOperator/better-adb-sync).

Answer (score 2):

1. If the files are on a removable µSD card, put the card in a USB reader and **copy** files directly. If the file system is not understood by Windows, e.g., ext4, use a third-party tool such as free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/). This is by far the fastest way to **copy** files. **N.B.: Do not attempt to delete files, or "move" them, because changes to the µSD card may make it unusable or destroy data.**

If you *must* work through the phone's operating system:

2. Make sure the phone is charging, and that it won't shut automatically during the operation.
3. Use Windows built-in [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), which is a more *robust* tool.
4. *Copy,* rather than *move*, files, and then delete all successfully copied. *Moving* requires two operations for each file: copying to the PC (fast), then deleting from flash memory (slow!).
5. Break the operation into segments, short enough to succeed separately. E.G., Copy all files beginning with "A" first, then "B"..."0"..."9", etc. Yes, it's slower and a nuisance, but may be the only way to succeed when the operation chokes on too many files at once.